# Plotting a Montgomery curve in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to graph a [Montgomery curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve) in MATLAB for a vector of X.  I am unsure how to handle the y term.   I have just been trying to simply plot the curve that is on the wikipedia page:

```
3y^2=x^3+7x^2+x
```

I can generate the points as a vector and plot them, but I would like to give X=[-10:10] to a function and plot it.  Any guidance or references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Easy-to-use function plotter like this,

```
ezplot('-3*y^2+x^3+7*x^2+x')
```

or

```
ezplot(@(x,y) -3*y^2+x^3+7*x^2+x)
```

You can also add an interval for your variables, `ezplot(fun2,[xymin,xymax])`.